# Which is better for no-cache pragmas? Setting it in the header or metatags or both?

Tags: php, zend-framework, no-cache

I'm currently using Zend Framework and for some of the actions in various controllers it has the pragmas set for no-cache. Some of them use metatags for this and others set the headers. Is it better to set it in the headers or in the metatags? Which is a browser more apt to listen to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Meta Tags are easy to use but usually not very effective. HTTP headers give you a lot of control over how both browser caches and proxies handle your objects. Therefore, I would definitely recommend you to use HTTP headers instead of HTML Meta Tags.

Also notice that PHP Headers prevent for both proxies and browsers from caching page, as far as I know you can't prevent proxies from caching page using HTML Meta Tags.

Another thing to take into consideration, from Microsoft Support:

> A page that Internet Explorer is browsing is not cached until half of
>   the 64 KB buffer is filled. Usually, metatags are inserted in the
>   header section of an HTML document, which appears at the beginning of
>   the document. When the HTML code is parsed, it is read from top to
>   bottom. When the  metatag is
>   read, Internet Explorer looks for the existence of the page in cache
>   at that exact moment. If it is there, it is removed.

So here is the way to go in your controllers:

`$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache', true);`

You could even write a ressource plugin that does it for you in all of your pages.

Comment: Thanks Liyali, I didn't think of proxies. Much appreciated.